# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method vision#startImageLabelDetector on channel google_ml_kit)

Tags: flutter

I was trying a demo code on the `google_ml_kit` plugin and ran into this error-

```
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method vision#startImageLabelDetector on channel google_ml_kit)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:61538/dart_sdk.js:5063:11)
at MethodChannel._invokeMethod (http://localhost:61538/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1555:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:61538/dart_sdk.js:40192:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:61538/dart_sdk.js:40062:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:61538/dart_sdk.js:34983:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:61538/dart_sdk.js:35551:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:61538/dart_sdk.js:35589:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:61538/dart_sdk.js:35437:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:61538/dart_sdk.js:35458:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:61538/dart_sdk.js:40330:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:61538/dart_sdk.js:40336:13)
    at http://localhost:61538/dart_sdk.js:35811:9
```

Here's the implementation-

```
import 'package:google_ml_kit/google_ml_kit.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

Future<List> runStuff() async {
  ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
  XFile? file = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  String path = file!.path;
  InputImage inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(path);
  ImageLabeler imageLabeler = GoogleMlKit.vision.imageLabeler();
  List out = await imageLabeler.processImage(inputImage);
  return out;
}
```

Comment: Are you running this on android, iOS or web?

Comment: i am running this on web

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exception appeared because the plug-in `google_ml_kit` is not supported for `web` but only iOS and android