# FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be correcte

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-mlkit

I want to add google machine language kit to my flutter project, when i do try adding the google ml kit this error appears, what could be the problem and how can i fix it?
i tried closing editor/ doing a flutter clean/ and closing my app
i have the latest firebase and firestore.

my initial problem was I used the image label kit at the start, when i tried to do so this appeared

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method vision#startImageLabelDetector on channel google_mlkit_image_labeler)
```

so I tried closing the editor and doing a

```
flutter clean
```

it did nothing but bring up the other problem which is

```
FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff.)
```

Comment: Where are you running this on whether it is an android or iOS platform?

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar android

Comment: @andwaojd Have you fixed this issue. Im facing the same now. Please help me on this.

Comment: No sorry I was unable to fix the issue.
really weird since without the package everything works fine and with it, it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you have encountered initially from plugins used are usually caused by either outdated plugin versions or the downloaded plugin not building properly.
Try to run these steps serially then close your code editor and check again:

`flutter clean`
`flutter pub get`
`flutter run`

When `flutter clean` is executed and then `flutter pub get` it will help generate build files again. You can also try to [update the plugin version](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_ml_kit/latest/) and check.
Find the example app [here](https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/tree/master/packages/google_ml_kit/example) and similar examples as below:

- [Missing Plugin exception issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74921013/missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for-method-visionstartimagelabel)
- [Missing Plugin exception on implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71088806/missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for-method-visionstartimagelabel)
- [Flutter unhandled exception missing plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687801/flutter-unhandled-exception-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for?rq=1)

Comment: didn't work, ps the first link was posted by me. I have no clue why this is happening or how to fix it. I also did post the issue on github, but no one replied.